# Onclick text how can I redirect to another XML page in android?

Tags: android

I am new to  android. Can I get to know Onclick text how can I redirect to another XML page in Android ?

Comment: What do you mean by redirect to another xml page? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to display another screen? or just want to navigate through other pages of the same XML?

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect to another xml through a button click, But here I think you have asked how to do it clicking on some text, for a example if you want to click on this text "click to sign up" and redirect you to the signup page.

So here is how I did it.

**1)for text click**

Inside Main Activity class
you write the following code.

```
//Text redirect. signup textview should be created within mainActivity.xml
        final TextView signup=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.signup);
        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v1) {
               Intent launchActivity1= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SignUp.class);
               startActivity(launchActivity1);

            }
        });
```

In the AndroidManifest file, You create a New Activity

```
<!-- Sign Up activity -->

         <activity
         android:name=".SignUp"
         android:label="@string/app_name">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.example.xxxx.SignUp"/>
             <categeory android:name="android.intent.categeory.LAUNCHER"/>
         </intent-filter>
         </activity>
```

*Sign Up Java class.* You make signup.xml appear inside this class by accessing it through the R.id.layout

```
package com.example.xxxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class SignUp extends Activity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);
    }
}
```

.

**2) for button click**

You will do the same as for Text click.

In MainActivity.java class

```
 final Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
     Intent launchactivity= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Details.class);                               
         startActivity(launchactivity);
```

Then you will create A new Activity in AndroidManifest.
You Have to have a Details.java class. Since you have mentioned to redirect to Details.class, according to this example.
Inside Details class like in previous access the relevant xml file.

"click here to signup" in the following image will redirect you to the signup.xml .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here that with 'new XML page' you refer to another view?

Most basic way to accomplish this is to make 2 activities with each a different layout (that XML file). On activity 1 add a button. In onclicklistener for that button start the other activity.

Use the visual tools in your IDE to create the activities. Use below code to switch to other activity:

```
public void startActivity2(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

More info at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

There  so many ways to do it i can't even describe them all :)
Possibly you thing about starting new activity. So you need to create new activity class with proper layout (in xml) and then start it with intent.
[Heres an example](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)